# mySQL: Loop to repeat query across a set of variables

Tags: mysql, loops, nested-loops

I have a dataset (in long format) which contains survey questions that patients completed throughout their stay in the hospital.

Initial data looks like this:

| PAT_ID | FLO_ID | ADMSN_DT | DISCH_DT | EATING | EATING DT | GROOMING | GROOMING DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1101 | 2019/11/25 10:51:59 | 2020/02/28 11:20:20 | 6 | 2019/11/26 14:48:12 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 1102 | 2019/11/25 10:51:59 | 2020/02/28 11:20:20 | NULL | NULL | 5 | 2020/02/28 09:20:20 |
| 2 | 1101 | 2021/11/18 11:31:00 | 2021/11/24 11:03:00 | 3 | 2021/11/23 9:54:27 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 1101 | 2021/11/18 11:31:00 | 2021/11/24 11:03:00 | 5 | 2021/11/24 10:15:37 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 1102 | 2021/11/18 11:31:00 | 2021/11/24 11:03:00 | NULL | NULL | 5 | 2021/11/20 10:08:42 |
| 2 | 1102 | 2021/11/18 11:31:00 | 2021/11/24 11:03:00 | NULL | NULL | 7 | 2021/11/21 09:48:42 |

The final data has to look like this: (F-First; L-Last)

| PAT_ID | F EATING | F EATING DT | L EATING | L EATING DT | F GROOMING | F GROOMING DT | L GROOMING | L GROOMING DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 2019/11/26 14:48:12 |  |  |  |  | 5 | 2019/11/26 14:48:55 |
| 2 | 3 | 2021/11/23 9:54:27 | 5 | 2021/11/24 10:15:37 | 7 | 2021/11/21 09:48:42 | 5 | 2021/11/20 10:08:42 |

Steps I took to generate my final table:

1. In cte1: Extract the survey items from my original table using the CTE
2. In cte2:
   a) Generate the time difference (in days) between when the item was administered and Admission/Discharge;
   b) Ordered the item by PAT_ID by DATETIME of the item administered in ascending and descending
   order; and
   c) Created individual row numbers for each of the columns
3. SELECT query: I created conditions to select out the relevant criteria
   a) Place results in FIRST if
   i) Ascending row = 1 & Descending row > 1; or
   ii) Ascending row = 1 & Descending row = 1 AND administered DATETIME is closer to Admission
   b) Place results in LAST if
   i) Descending row = 1 and Ascending row > 1; or
   ii) Ascending row = 1 & Descending row = 1 AND administered DATETIME is closer to Discharge
4. Repeat step 3) for the accompanying DATETIME of the variable.
5. Rearrange the data so that each row represents a patient.

I had written a set of cumbersome codes to achieve what I want. However, the fact that I need to repeat the codes 21 times (there are a total of 21 items in the survey), makes it very inefficient.

Can someone please advise how I should improve the codes so that I can achieve the same outcome? Is it possible to use a loop to run through the queries across the different variables?

```
WITH cte1 AS (

    SELECT

        HSP.PAT_ID, 
        MEAS.FLO_ID,
        HSP.ADMSN_DATETIME,
        HSP.DISCH_DATETIME,

        CASE WHEN MEAS.FLO_ID = '1101' THEN MEAS.MEAS_VALUE ELSE NULL END "EATING",
        CASE WHEN MEAS.FLO_ID = '1101' THEN MEAS.ENTRY_TIME ELSE NULL END "EATING DATETIME",

        CASE WHEN MEAS.FLO_ID = '1102' THEN MEAS.MEAS_VALUE ELSE NULL END  "GROOMING",
        CASE WHEN MEAS.FLO_ID = '1102' THEN MEAS.ENTRY_TIME ELSE NULL END  "GROOMING DATETIME"

    FROM HSP
        INNER JOIN MEAS
            ON HSP.FLO_ID = MEAS.FLO_ID

    WHERE MEAS.FLO_ID IN ('1101','1102')                                        
    
),

cte2 AS (


    select
        cte1.PAT_ID,
        cte1.ADMSN_DATETIME,
        cte1.DISCH_DATETIME,

        cte1.[EATING],
        cte1.[EATING DATETIME],
        DATEDIFF( DAY, CAST(cte1.ADMSN_DATETIME AS DATE), CAST(cte1.[EATING DATETIME] AS DATE)) "EATING:RECORD-ADMSN",
        DATEDIFF( DAY, CAST(cte1.[EATING DATETIME] AS DATE), CAST(cte1.DISCH_DATETIME AS DATE)) "EATING:DISCH-RECORD",
        CASE WHEN cte1.[EATING] is null then null else ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by cte1.PAT_ID ORDER BY cte1.[EATING DATETIME] DESC ) END "LAST EATING ROWNO",
        ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by cte1.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID ORDER BY ( CASE WHEN cte1.[DATEEATING TIME] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ), cte1.[EATING DATETIME] ASC )  "FIRST EATING ROW",
        
        cte1.[GROOMING],
        cte1.[GROOMING DATETIME],
        DATEDIFF( DAY, CAST(cte1.ADMSN_DATETIME AS DATE), CAST(cte1.[GROOMING DATETIME] AS DATE)) "GROOMING:RECORD-ADMSN",
        DATEDIFF( DAY, CAST(cte1.[GROOMING DATETIME RECORDED] AS DATE), CAST(cte1.DISCH_TIME AS DATE)) "GROOMING:DISCH-RECORD",
        CASE WHEN cte1.[GROOMING] is null then null else ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by cte1.PAT_ID ORDER BY cte1.[GROOMING DATETIME] DESC ) END "LAST GROOMING ROWNO",
        ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by cte1.PAT_ID ORDER BY ( CASE WHEN cte1.[GROOMING DATETIME] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ), cte1.[GROOMING DATETIME] ASC )  "FIRST GROOMING ROW",

FROM cte1
    
)

SELECT 
    cte2.PAT_ID, 
    
    MAX( CASE WHEN (cte2.[FIRST EATING ROW] = 1 AND cte2.[LAST EATING ROWNO] > 1
            OR (cte2.[FIRST EATING ROW] = 1 AND cte2.[LAST EATING ROWNO] = 1 
            AND cte2.[EATING:RECORD-ADMSN] < cte2.[EATING:DISCH-RECORD]) ) THEN cte2.[EATING] ELSE NULL END ) "FIRST FIMS:EATING",
    MAX( CASE WHEN (cte2.[FIRST EATING ROW] = 1 AND cte2.[LAST EATING ROWNO] > 1
            OR (cte2.[FIRST EATING ROW] = 1 AND cte2.[LAST EATING ROWNO] = 1 
            AND cte2.[EATING:RECORD-ADMSN] < cte2.[EATING:DISCH-RECORD]) ) THEN cte2.[EATING DATETIME] ELSE NULL END ) "FIRST EATING DATETIME",
    MAX( CASE WHEN (cte2.[FIRST EATING ROW] > 1 AND cte2.[LAST EATING ROWNO] = 1
            OR (cte2.[FIRST EATING ROW] = 1 AND cte2.[LAST EATING ROWNO] = 1 
            AND cte2.[EATING:RECORD-ADMSN] > cte2.[EATING:DISCH-RECORD]) ) THEN cte2.[EATING] ELSE NULL END ) "LAST EATING",
    MAX( CASE WHEN (cte2.[FIRST EATING ROW] > 1 AND cte2.[LAST EATING ROWNO] = 1
            OR (cte2.[FIRST EATING ROW] = 1 AND cte2.[LAST EATING ROWNO] = 1 
            AND cte2.[EATING:RECORD-ADMSN] > cte2.[EATING:DISCH-RECORD]) ) THEN cte2.[EATING DATETIME] ELSE NULL END ) "LAST EATING DATETIME"

    MAX( CASE WHEN (cte2.[FIRST GROOMING ROW] = 1 AND cte2.[LAST GROOMING ROWNO] > 1
            OR (cte2.[FIRST GROOMING ROW] = 1 AND cte2.[LAST GROOMING ROWNO] = 1 
            AND cte2.[GROOMING:RECORD-ADMSN] < cte2.[GROOMING:DISCH-RECORD]) ) THEN cte2.[GROOMING] ELSE NULL END ) "FIRST GROOMING",
    MAX( CASE WHEN (cte2.[FIRST GROOMING ROW] = 1 AND cte2.[LAST GROOMING ROWNO] > 1
            OR (cte2.[FIRST GROOMING ROW] = 1 AND cte2.[LAST GROOMING ROWNO] = 1 
            AND cte2.[GROOMING:RECORD-ADMSN] < cte2.[GROOMING:DISCH-RECORD]) ) THEN cte2.GROOMING TIME RECORDED] ELSE NULL END ) "FIRST GROOMING DATETIME",
    MAX( CASE WHEN (cte2.[FIRST GROOMING ROW] > 1 AND cte2.[LAST GROOMING ROWNO] = 1
            OR (cte2.[FIRST GROOMING ROW] = 1 AND cte2.[LAST GROOMING ROWNO] = 1 
            AND cte2.[GROOMING:RECORD-ADMSN] > cte2.[GROOMING:DISCH-RECORD]) ) THEN cte2.[GROOMING] ELSE NULL END ) "LAST GROOMING",
    MAX( CASE WHEN (cte2.[FIRST GROOMING ROW] > 1 AND cte2.[LAST GROOMING ROWNO] = 1
            OR (cte2.[FIRST GROOMING ROW] = 1 AND cte2.[LAST GROOMING ROWNO] = 1 
            AND cte2.[GROOMING:RECORD-ADMSN] > cte2.[GROOMING:DISCH-RECORD]) ) THEN cte2.[GROOMING DATETIME] ELSE NULL END ) "LAST GROOMING DATETIME"
FROM cte2
    
    GROUP BY cte2.PAT_ID
    ORDER BY cte2.PAT_ID
```